# By what amount does the Masuda method increase the chance of breeding a Shiny?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Right now, in the daycare, I have a JPN Ditto and a SPN Eevee, and I am breeding them for hopes at a Shiny Eevee. To what amount does this change the original 1/8000 (Around there) to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current modifier for the Masuda method isn't known, not enough testing has been done. However, unless things have changed since Generation V, we can assume that the Masuda modifier increases the chance of shinies by a factor of 6.

Comment: Bringing it from 1/8192 (guess) to 7/8192?

Comment: Multiplicative factor, so 3/4096.

Comment: That is really a difference :O

Comment: `However, in Generation V, it is boosted even further from 1 in 8,192 to 1 in 1,365.3. Generation VI has increased the likelihood even further, with the rate being reduced even further.` This comes from [Serebii.](http://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml) So it's better than 1/1365.3, or 3/4096, @Yuki.

Comment: Whether or not this is true, but I've recently heard it was somewhere around 1/800 chance for getting a shiny via masuda method.